# Conflicts with angular2 and @angular node modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

At present I am using node.js v5.7.0. When installing from npm, sometimes I am able to see @angular and sometimes angular2 folders.

I am unable to overcome these errors because of this confusion.

> Error:"Cannot find @angular"

```
    package.json:


  {
 "name": "PBar",
 "version": "3.6.0",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
 "lite": "lite-server",
 "postinstall": "typings install",
 "tsc": "tsc",
 "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
 "typings": "typings"
 },
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
 "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
 "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
 "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "systemjs": "0.19.27",
 "core-js": "^2.4.0",
 "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
 "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
 "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
 "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
 "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
 "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
 "typescript": "^1.8.10",
 "typings":"^1.0.4"
 }
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code including package.json and  systemjs.config.js

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder completely and do a fresh npm install

Comment: yaa i can post my json :